# Ansible: using an inventory variable works, but not with an environement variable

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Get environement
      ansible.builtin.setup:
        gather_subset:
          - "!all"
          - "!any"
          - "env"
          - "virtual"

    - name: Execute actions on Gitlab
      gitlab_custom_module:
        url: "{{ ansible_env['CI_SERVER_URL'] }}"
        private_token: "{{ mytoken }}"
        project_path: "{{ ansible_env['CI_PROJECT_PATH'] }}"
        branch_name: "{{ ansible_env['CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'] }}"
        current_pipeline_id: "{{ ansible_env['CI_PIPELINE_ID'] }}"
```

The goal is to fetch some information from a Gitlab instance and execute actions.
This playbook is ran inside a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline.
Here is the code for the custom module:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

__metaclass__ = type

import gitlab
from ansible.errors import AnsibleActionFail, AnsibleError
from ansible.module_utils.common.text.converters import to_native
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase
from ansible.utils.display import Display

display = Display()


class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        """handler for template operations"""
        self._supports_check_mode = False

        if task_vars is None:
            task_vars = dict()

        result = super().run(tmp, task_vars)
        url = self._task.args.get("url")
        verify_ssl = self._task.args.get("verify_ssl", True)
        private_token = self._task.args.get("private_token")
        project_path = self._task.args.get("project_path")
        branch_name = self._task.args.get("branch_name", "master")
        current_pipeline_id = int(self._task.args.get("current_pipeline_id"))

        self.g = gitlab.Gitlab(url, ssl_verify=verify_ssl, private_token=str(private_token))
        self.project = self.g.projects.get(project_path)
        self.running_pipelines = self.project.pipelines.list(
            order_by="id", status="running", sort="desc", ref=branch_name
        )

        if (pipe := len(self.running_pipelines)) == 1 and int(
            self.running_pipelines[0].id
        ) == current_pipeline_id:

            msg = f"{pipe} pipelines running in {project_path} on branch {branch_name}"
            result["failed"] = False
            result["msg"] = msg
        elif pipe == 0:
            msg = f"No pipeline is running under {project_path} on branch {branch_name}"
            raise AnsibleError(to_native(msg))
        else:
            msg = f"{pipe} pipelines running in {project_path} on branch {branch_name}"
            result["failed"] = True
            result["msg"] = msg

        return result
```

When I try to access `mytoken`, which is declared in a `vault.yml` file located in the `host_vars` directory, the module works as expected.

However, when I declare my variable in the CI/CD variables and then try to access it like the other ones (`"{{ ansible_env['MYTOKEN'] }}"` or `"{{ lookup('env', 'MYTOKEN' }}"`), the module fails:

```
    - name: Execute actions on Gitlab
      gitlab_custom_module:
        url: "{{ ansible_env['CI_SERVER_URL'] }}"
        private_token: "{{ ansible_env['MYTOKEN'] }}"
        project_path: "{{ ansible_env['CI_PROJECT_PATH'] }}"
        branch_name: "{{ ansible_env['CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'] }}"
        current_pipeline_id: "{{ ansible_env['CI_PIPELINE_ID'] }}"
```

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Header part ('<token>') from {'MYTOKEN': '<token>'} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText'>
```

I added debug steps and I get the expected value:

```
    - name: Getting var value
      debug:
        var: ansible_env.MYTOKEN

    - name: Getting var value with lookup
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('env', 'MYTOKEN') }}"
```

I tried to cast it as a string (in the playbook and in the python module) but nothing works, unless I use the vaulted variable.

Any ideas about this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your custom module is broken. Without being able to see the code we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: An alternative may be to tell ansible that you "trust" the string values found in the `ansible_env` dict via `"{{ ansible_env['MYTOKEN'] | string }}"` but without more debugging information, we're left to just guess

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answers!

@mdaniel; I've tried to do that as well but nothing changes sadly. 
@flowerysong, I've edited my post and added the module code.

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue with the code that you provided. I can get a similar failure with `requests>=2.28.0` (https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6159), but in order to do so I have to remove the `str` cast.